# Delete expired products from SQLite and treeview

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete

I want to delete elements at today's date. But this statement doesn't work.

```
cur.execute("DELTE FROM medicine WHERE date DATE('now') AND DATE('now', '-1 day')")
     try:
        tree.delete(cur)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column's `date` format is `YYYY-MM-DD` then you need this statement:

```
DELETE FROM medicine WHERE date = DATE('now')
```

or:

```
DELETE FROM medicine WHERE date = CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Yes the format is correct. But for is code for deleting items from treeview right?

Comment: Yes but I display these rows in tkinter in treeview

Comment: Your question is tagged SQLite. You provided a non working sql statement and my answer is about this issue. If you want something more after that then ask a new question where you explain what you want.